# PostgreSQL version compatible with Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, 32-bit

I have tried to install PostgreSQL 10.6 on Win 7 SP1 32 bit and I got following error after trying to run pgadmin4:

> "postgresql application server could not be contacted"

With PostgradeSQL version 9.6.21 I got:

> "An error occurred initializing the application server: Failed to launch application server, server thread existing"

Do you have any idea what could be wrong, or do you have experience with a version that is working fine on Win 7 SP1 32bit?
Thanks

Comment: the first error message could be because pgadmin couldn't see the postgresql , which could be as simple as some permission issue. did you make sure its not pgadmin permission issue?

Comment: @eshirvana I have started gpadmin4 as administrator, I really don't have idea what else I can do about that.

Comment: First step try to connect to postgresql from shell and make a username with password . Are you able to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Please install PostgreSQL again and uncheck pgadmin 4 package as it would be the new version available, which will not be supported for windows 7 32 or 64 bit.
only pgadmin4  upto v4.30 is compatible with windows 7 os.

You need to download pgadmin v4.30 or less separately from Postgresql download archives.

link:https://pgadmin-archive.postgresql.org/pgadmin4/v4.30/windows/index.html
or just google pgadmin4 v4.30 download.

Install v4.30. It will work for sure.Also select chrome as browser for opening pgadmin 4.

I had same problem, and it worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYN1m.png)

Comment: I've installed postgres 13 with Pgadmin4.3 (on Win7). But it throws error when view all rows -
ERROR:  column rel.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT rel.relhasoids AS has_oids

Comment: @RahulDey How could you install PG 13 on a **32 bit** Win7? _(This question is related to 32bit only.)_